The email signature block is not loading with my Add-In
I’m working on developing my first Add-In for Outlook 365/Windows 10. In theory, it’s quite simple—it’s a drop-down menu with two options. Each option opens a new email and loads a different template, depending on the selection.
So far, the menu is functioning smoothly. Selecting option A displays the corresponding template, and the same goes for option B.
However, I’m facing a problem: I can’t get the user’s signature to load automatically as expected, even though the signature is properly configured and set as the default for new emails.
Attached you will find my manifest.xml and commands.ts
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
<Id>2eb95a7a-bc4a-4f53-bc6f-ba64b72d8663</Id>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="NewClientMatter"/>
<Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
<AppDomains>
<AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
<Hosts>
<Host Name="Mailbox"/>
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
<Sets>
<Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5"/>
</Sets>
</Requirements>
<FormSettings>
<Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
<DesktopSettings>
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
<RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
</DesktopSettings>
</Form>
</FormSettings>
<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
</Rule>
<DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
<Requirements>
<bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
<bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
</bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
<Hosts>
<Host xsi:type="MailHost">
<DesktopFormFactor>
<FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
<OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
<Group id="msgReadGroup">
<Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
<Control xsi:type="Menu" id="DropdownMenu">
<Label resid="DropdownMenu.Label"/>
<Supertip>
<Title resid="DropdownMenu.Label"/>
<Description resid="DropdownMenu.Tooltip"/>
</Supertip>
<Icon>
<bt:Image size="16" resid="MenuIcon.16x16"/>
<bt:Image size="32" resid="MenuIcon.32x32"/>
<bt:Image size="80" resid="MenuIcon.80x80"/>
</Icon>
<Items>
<Item id="InternalAction">
<Label resid="InternalAction.Label"/>
<Supertip>
<Title resid="InternalAction.Label"/>
<Description resid="InternalAction.Tooltip"/>
</Supertip>
<Icon>
<bt:Image size="16" resid="InternalIcon.16x16"/>
<bt:Image size="32" resid="InternalIcon.32x32"/>
<bt:Image size="80" resid="InternalIcon.80x80"/>
</Icon>
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
<FunctionName>handleInternalAction</FunctionName>
</Action>
</Item>
<Item id="ExternalAction">
<Label resid="ExternalAction.Label"/>
<Supertip>
<Title resid="ExternalAction.Label"/>
<Description resid="ExternalAction.Tooltip"/>
</Supertip>
<Icon>
<bt:Image size="16" resid="ExternalIcon.16x16"/>
<bt:Image size="32" resid="ExternalIcon.32x32"/>
<bt:Image size="80" resid="ExternalIcon.80x80"/>
</Icon>
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
<FunctionName>handleExternalAction</FunctionName>
</Action>
</Item>
</Items>
</Control>
</Group>
</OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
</DesktopFormFactor>
</Host>
</Hosts>
<Resources>
<bt:Images>
<bt:Image id="MenuIcon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu-icon-16.png"/>
<bt:Image id="MenuIcon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu-icon-32.png"/>
<bt:Image id="MenuIcon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu-icon-80.png"/>
<bt:Image id="InternalIcon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/int-16.png"/>
<bt:Image id="InternalIcon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/int-32.png"/>
<bt:Image id="InternalIcon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/int-80.png"/>
<bt:Image id="ExternalIcon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ext-16.png"/>
<bt:Image id="ExternalIcon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ext-32.png"/>
<bt:Image id="ExternalIcon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ext-80.png"/>
</bt:Images>
<bt:Urls>
<bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
<bt:Url id="CommandsJs.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands/commands.js"/>
</bt:Urls>
<bt:ShortStrings>
<bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="New Client/Matter"/>
<bt:String id="DropdownMenu.Label" DefaultValue="Choose Action"/>
<bt:String id="InternalAction.Label" DefaultValue="Internal"/>
<bt:String id="ExternalAction.Label" DefaultValue="External"/>
</bt:ShortStrings>
<bt:LongStrings>
<bt:String id="DropdownMenu.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Select an action to perform."/>
<bt:String id="InternalAction.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens an internal email template."/>
<bt:String id="ExternalAction.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens an external email template."/>
</bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>

commands.ts
/* global Office */

Office.onReady(function (info) {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    Office.actions.associate("handleInternalAction", handleInternalAction);
    Office.actions.associate("handleExternalAction", handleExternalAction);
  }
});

/**
 * Handles the "Internal" action.
 * @param event The Office Add-in event.
 */
function handleInternalAction(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event): void {
  openEmailTemplate("internal", event);
}

/**
 * Handles the "External" action.
 * @param event The Office Add-in event.
 */
function handleExternalAction(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event): void {
  openEmailTemplate("external", event);
}

/**
 * Opens an email template with the user's signature.
 * @param templateType The type of template ("internal" or "external").
 * @param event The Office Add-in event.
 */
function openEmailTemplate(templateType: string, event: Office.AddinCommands.Event): void {
  let templateBody: string;
  let subject: string;
  
  if (templateType === "internal") {
    templateBody = `
      My fields<br/><br/>
    `;
    subject = "(Internal)";
  } else if (templateType === "external") {
    templateBody = `
      My fields<br/><br/>
    `;
    subject = "(External)";
  } else {
    console.error("Invalid template type specified:", templateType);
    event.completed();
    return;
  }

  // Open a new email draft
  Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({
    subject,
    htmlBody: templateBody,
  });

  // Function to check draft readiness and insert the signature
  const checkDraftReady = () => {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, (result) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        const userSignature = result.value || "";
        if (userSignature) {
          const combinedBody = `
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
              </head>
              <body>
                ${templateBody}  <!-- Template Body -->
                <br/><br/>
                ${userSignature}  <!-- User Signature -->
              </body>
            </html>
          `;

          Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
            combinedBody,
            { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html },
            (setResult) => {
              if (setResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.error("Failed to set email body:", setResult.error);
              }
              event.completed();  // Ensure event is completed after the set operation
            }
          );
        } else {
          console.warn("User's signature not available.");
          event.completed();
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to get user's signature. Retrying...", result.error);
        setTimeout(checkDraftReady, 500); // Retry after a short delay
      }
    });
  };

  setTimeout(checkDraftReady, 500); // Initial retry delay
}


Thank you so much for your support!

Do you mean userSignature comes up empty?

Hello @DmitryStreblechenko, Thank you for your reply.  The signature is not visible, I think it comes empty.

Try to verify under the debugger. Outlook inserts the signature asynchronously after the message is shown as long as the message body is not modified. Also keep in mind that you cannot concatenate two well-formed HTML documents and expect a valid HTML document as the result; the two must be merged.

Hello,
Thank you for replying. Your perspective is very valid, and I hadn’t really thought about it.
Maybe that’s the problem? I’m essentially working with two HTML objects: the email template, which is created as you can see in real time inside the commands.TS, and the signature, which is another HTML object.
Could you guide me on how you think I could merge the template with the signature into a single object?
Thank you very much,

Firstly, try to verify in the debugger that you do get the signature HTML. The easiest way to merge two HTML strings is to find the position of the <body> tag (or </body> depending on where you are inserting) in one HTML string, then insert the value between the <body> and </body> tags of the second HTML string. You'll lose the styles defined in the header, but you can deal with that too.

I have update the commands.ts on the original message, but it's remain unchanged. I mean, the signature is not showed up.

Did you check if you actually get the signature?

In OWA the Add-In is working smoothly but nor in Outlook Desktop. I mean in the last one the signature is not showing up.

I wouldn't be surprised there are differences like that - that just tells me that web addin run-time does not see the newly added signature for some time.

Hello Dmitry, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to tell me. I've increased the time in the setTimeout to 2 seconds, but there's no change. I'm looking into how to set enable the debugger in Outlook, but so far, no luck. I also created a temporary signature and set it as the default. The result was interesting because, for a split second, the signature loaded and then disappeared as the template was applied. I think the problem is that the template is being applied over the signature. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this clearly or if you understand what I'm trying to say. Thank you.
